# How can I use a DropDownList to limit user selection in a Database INSERT?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am trying to limit the selection of an INSERT using a DropDownList, my TextBox all work correctly but I cannot seem to figure out how to use a DropDownList in a similar fashion.

Here is my current code-behind:

```
private void _subInsert(RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox txtPostTitle = (TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("txt_post_titleI"); // Find the control with the information you wish to store
    TextBox txtPostBody = (TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("txt_post_bodyI");
    TextBox txtPostAuthor = (TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("txt_post_authorI");
    DropDownList ddlPostType = (DropDownList)e.Item.FindControl("ddl_post_typeI");

    sds_main.InsertParameters["post_title"].DefaultValue = txtPostTitle.Text; // Insert information into this location in the DB
    sds_main.InsertParameters["post_body"].DefaultValue = txtPostBody.Text;
    sds_main.InsertParameters["post_author"].DefaultValue = txtPostAuthor.Text;
    sds_main.InsertParameters["post_type"].DefaultValue = ddlPostType.SelectedValue.ToString();

    sds_main.Insert(); // Perform Insert
}
```

The TextBoxes all insert correctly, but the DropDownList does not allow me to use the SelectedValue in the Insert. I am getting a "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error.

This is the code for my SQLDataSource control on the presentation page:

```
    <asp:SqlDataSource
    id="sds_main"
    runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:fntn0070DBConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [blogTest]" 
        DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [blogTest] WHERE [id] = @id" 
        InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [blogTest] ([post_title], [post_body], [post_author], [post_type]) VALUES (@post_title, @post_body, @post_author, @post_type)" 

        UpdateCommand="UPDATE [blogTest] SET [post_title] = @post_title, [post_body] = @post_body, [post_author] = @post_author, [post_type] = @post_type WHERE [id] = @id" >
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="id" Type="Int32" />
    </DeleteParameters>
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="post_title" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="post_body" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="post_date" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="post_author" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="post_type" Type="String" />
    </InsertParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="post_title" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="post_body" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="post_author" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="post_type" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="id" Type="Int32" />
    </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

And this is my DDL on the presentation page:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_postTypeI" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem>Web Development</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Photography</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Other</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

I have tried my best to search for this problem on Google and StackOverflow but have only be able to find information on how to bind data to the DDL.

I am very new to ASP.NET 4, just starting to learn it in my web development course so please ELI5 if you are able to answer. Thanks in advance for any help you are able to provide.

Answer (score 0):

you can not use it directly without giving value of dropdown list.

try this

```
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_postTypeI" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Value="Web Development">Web Development</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Photography">Photography</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Other">Other</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

and then try to insert in data , if you are passing integer value then use value="1" otherwise it will throw an error.

Thanks,

Comment: Wow, didn't realise how simple the fix was. Thank you very much.